# Validity of list of articulation points in a graph after a node is deleted

Tags: graphs

Say I have a bidirectional graph `G` and I have the list of articulation points and bridges of this graph. Say, the list of articulation points is `ap[]` and the list of bridges are `bridges[]`. Now, if I remove a node which does not belong to the list of `ap[]`, meaning, this node is not an articulation point and deleting this node will not divide the nodes of this graph into different connected components. Now, do I have to update the list of the articulation points `ap[]`? I mean after deleting the node, is it possible that some more node(s) in the graph will become articulation points? The same question is for the list of bridges. If I remove an edge which is not a bridge in the graph, after deleting it, is it possible that some more existing edge(s) will become bridge?

Comment: [This question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68332/584) is somewhat related; it may be worthwhile to check the sources provided in the answer.

Comment: Learned some new things. Thanks! So is it possible the list of articulation points will be invalid after deleting a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes. Look at this graph:

- $V=\{1,2,3,4\}$
- $E=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{4,1\}\}$

There is neither articulation point nor bridge. But if you delete any node/edge...